# Dynamic DisplayTag Component for Apache Wicket?

Tags: dynamic, struts, wicket, displaytag

I need a dynamic DisplayTag component for Wicket. What I want to do is, I will just bind this DisplayTag component to a dynamic data-source which contains changeable data-set, and the component will automatically create a table including dynamic columns and rows in the data-set.

I can do this in Struts framework by using DisplayTag component. Is there any simple way to do the same with Wicket? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like DataTable will do exactly what you need. See this example -

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/simple-sortable-datatable-example.html